# IndexedDB: Open cursor on specific entry without iteration

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, database-cursor

In my indexedDB database I need to open a cursor on one specific entry, because I want to call the `update`-function of the cursor on that entry to update an attribute of the object stored there.

My current implementation is to iterate over the objectstore until the cursor points to the object with the given key, but since I already know the key of the object I want to find, it seems like quite a waste to iterate over all entries, when I also could just get it via the key.

Is there a way to open a cursor on a result of a query like `objectstore.get(_key_).openCursor()` ?

Note: I know that I could also use `objectstore.put(...)` to update a specific value, but I try to avoid this as it would be a major problem if a new entry was created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `objectStore.openCursor(_key_)`, [where `_key_` is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/openCursor):

> A key or IDBKeyRange to be queried. If a single valid key is passed, this will default to a range containing only that key. If nothing is passed, this will default to a key range that selects all the records in this object store.